Understanding this BLDC single shunt waveform
Let me introduce my setup and two pics first, then I'll ask my question.
This is a simplified schematic of my setup. I am trying to understand the output waveform from the single shunt in this 3 phase BLDC circuit. I am running it through a low pass filter to clean things up. The PWM channels represent the state of the half bridge - low means low side FET is on, high means high side FET is on.
Note: It should go without saying but just incase, I will talk about shunt voltage. I know it represents total motor coil current, hence why it is there, and why I'm measuring the voltage. Please inform me if this is incorrect.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here are the two pictures in question:


What I'm having trouble understanding is why the output waveform responds differently to the timing of the green edge. In in the first picture, the shunt voltage sharply increases upon the green channel going from low to high (this seems to make intuitive sense to me). However, in the second picture, when the green channel goes high, it causes a voltage drop in the shunt. Why is this so? And yes, going along with this thought, there's a spot inbetween where the green channel going high causes no shunt voltage change.
I think I may be overthinking this entirely. Thanks for your help.
